Cart function Glitch (incrementing and decrementing product amount)
I'm building a shopping cart and i encountered a problem,
this cart takes in a product, if a product already exist, increment its amount
for decrementing if the item amount is ===1, add to cart
This is my Add to cart function
addToCart(product:Product){
  const ls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartList') || '[]') as Product[] | null;

  let productAlreadyInCart = false;
  // Check if the product is already in the cart
  for (let item of this.cartItemList) {
    if (item.name === product.name) {
      // If the product is already in the cart, increment its amount and price
      item.amount ++
      item.price = product.price * item.amount;
      productAlreadyInCart = true;
      localStorage.setItem('cartList', JSON.stringify(ls))
      console.log(this.total,'item amount incremented')
      break; // No need to continue looping once found
      // console.log(this.total);
    }

  }
  // If the product is not in the cart, add it
  if(!productAlreadyInCart) {
    // get list of produts in local storage and append
    const newData = this.cartItemList.push({ ...product, amount: 1 });
    localStorage.setItem('cartList', JSON.stringify(newData))
    console.log('item added successfully')
  }
  // Update total
  this.getTotal();
  console.log(this.total, 'new item');
}

and i decrement, remove it from the array, otherwise just decrement the amount
now the incrementing works, Increment
incrementQuantity(product:Product){
  console.log('item amount decremented', product)
  // confirm if item exist
  let item = this.cartItemList.find(item => item.name === product.name)
  if(item){
    item.amount +=1
    item.price += product.price
  }
  this.getTotal();
}

my issue now is the decrementing.
to understand the issue better i will create a use case, however you can skip and just look at the code snippets in my solution attempts
decrement
(Use case)
we wont touch on the incrementing, again, it works
for the decrement however, imagine we have a vase in our cart at $100,
product:Product[] =[{
    name: 'vase',
    price: 100,
    description:'ceramic',
    image: '../assets/vase.png',
    BlackFridaySale: true,
    amount: 0 //when we add an item the amount is set to 1
}]

when we increment to 3 vases, the price updates to 300$, however when i decrement, instead of remove 100 dollars which is the price of one, it removes the whole $300 and sets the price to 0
decremnetQuantity(product: Product){
  for (let i = 0; i < this.cartItemList.length; i++) {
    const item = this.cartItemList[i];
    if (item.name === product.name) {
      if (item.amount === 1) {
        this.total -= item.price;
        this.cartItemList.splice(i, 1);
      } else {
        item.amount--;
        item.price -= product.price;
      }
      // this.updateCart();
      this.getTotal();
      break;
    }
  }
}

I'd appreciate some insight
it seems i am somehow editing the same instance of my items in the array and i don't know where its coming from
i tried a for loop in the decrement logic, I'll also put the rest of the important snippets so i don't leave any gray area

Please do not post your code as image. See this post.

Please insert console.log(item); before if (item.amount === 1) { in decremnetQuantity and show console log.

this is the console log
{
"name": "Ornamental Vase",
"price": 0,
"description": "vase.",
"image": "../assets/Vase.png",
"BlackFridaySale": false,
"amount": 1
}
the product price is 70k, i incremented to 2 (140k) before attempting to decrement and this is the output @N.F.

Somewhere else in your code set the amount to 1. One possibilty is you create a shallow copy of the cartItemList element and set amount  to 1 for the copied item.

the amount is the Item quantity, and is set to one when i add item into the cart array (see my add to cart function)
however, could you elaborate on the shallow copy? what would that look like in this context? @N.F.
